# How do I take row values from a column and combine them, sep by "," based on different column value?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidy

I am working with Proteomic data and testing differences between versions of the analysis software. We are wanting to have a table that lets us know in what versions of the software the proteins appear.

Below is a simplified version of the data table I currently have:

```
Version Protein.ID Protein name
1.1     A          name 1
1.2     A          name 1
1.1     B          name 2
1.2     B          name 2
```

I want my table to look like this:

```
Version   Protein.ID Protein name
1.1, 1.2  A          name 1
1.1, 1.2  B          name 2
```

I have been looking for 2 days on here and the web and can not find a solution.

I have tried using spread, and aggregate but neither worked. I either got a huge number of columns or a single column lacking the information I was after. I tried using some base R commands like paste but could not get rid of duplicate values.

Example of something I tried:

```r
allver.mergeVerID <- spread(allver.ids, Protein.ID, Ver.ID.Porder)
```

```
Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys. 
Keys are shared for 5311 rows:
```

I also get this error using

```r
allver.mergeVerID <- allver.ids %>% group_by(Protein.ID) %>% 
  summarise(Ver.ID.Porder= toString(Ver.ID.Porder), )
```

**OR**

```r
allver.mergeVerID <- aggregate(Ver.ID.Porder ~ Protein.ID, allver.ids, toString)
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way.  After grouping by 'Protein.ID', `summarise` the 'Version' by `paste`ing the elements together

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Protein.ID, `Protein name`) %>%
  summarise(Version = toString(Version))
```

---

Or with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(Version ~ Protein.ID + `Protein name`, df1, toString)
#  Protein.ID Protein name  Version
#1          A       name 1 1.1, 1.2
#2          B       name 2 1.1, 1.2
```

NOTE: Both solutions match the expected output

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Version = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.1, 1.2),
     Protein.ID = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), `Protein name` = c('name 1', 
  'name 1', 'name 2', 'name 2'), check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: these both kind of work but I still get the error listed above... Where would I add the code to keep all other columns in the table?

Comment: @Ryandcalvert. You showed only two columns and my solution is based on that example

Comment: I updated the question with the additional column I would like to keep

Comment: @Ryandcalvert. Updated the code as well

Comment: thank you, I'll try this... any suggestion about the error I'm getting?

Comment: I like @Ryandcalvert solution. I'd just add as.data.frame() to the dplyr solution to make it a data frame.

Comment: You get the error because you're using only one of the variables as key. You need to use both (ID and name).